# Product info changes after hook execution

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I have problem with Wordpress hook save_post.

When you just save post, it work ok.
But when you use 'Quick edit', hook execute function and only then save post. 
For example:
I have function which send mail with product quantity after post save. So if you change quantity on product edit page and update it - you receive new quantity. But if you change quantity via quick edit - you receive on email old quantity.

Answer (score 0):

The Quick Edit Function is using AJAX and need a diffrent aproach to Hook in.

See this detailed Post for more Info:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/60779

Comment: Try answer the question without just referring to a link

Comment: Not sure that link help me